# Erro em cálculo

Tags: java

Olá, estou com um projeto de uma calculadora de consórcio que está apresentando erro. Ela recebe do usuário os seguintes dados:

- Valor do consórcio
- Quantidade de meses
- % do fundo de reserva
- % da taxa administrativa

Após isso ele calcula o valor da parcela mensal.

O meu problema é o seguinte: Se eu colocar a quantidade de meses 10 funciona se colocar 15 já dá erro.

Segue o código:

```
BigDecimal cota = new BigDecimal(jTextField1.getText());
BigDecimal prazo = new BigDecimal(jTextField2.getText());
BigDecimal reserva = new BigDecimal(jTextField3.getText());
BigDecimal adm = new BigDecimal(jTextField4.getText());

DecimalFormat decimal = new DecimalFormat("0.##");

//Calculo Fundo Comum
BigDecimal pc = new BigDecimal("100");
BigDecimal percentualMensal = pc.divide(prazo);
BigDecimal parcelaMensal = percentualMensal.multiply(cota);
BigDecimal parcelaMensal1 = parcelaMensal.divide(pc);

//Calculo Taxa Administrativa
BigDecimal a1 = adm.divide(prazo);
BigDecimal parcelaAdm = a1.multiply(cota);
BigDecimal parcelaAdm1 = parcelaAdm.divide(pc);

//Calculo Fundo Reserva
BigDecimal r1 = reserva.divide(prazo);
BigDecimal parcelaReserva = cota.multiply(r1);
BigDecimal parcelaReserva1 = parcelaReserva.divide(pc);

BigDecimal calculo = parcelaMensal1.add(parcelaAdm1.add(parcelaReserva1));

String a = decimal.format(calculo);

jLabel5.setText("Valor: "+a);
```

Comment: Mas qual é o erro?

Comment: `pc.divide(prazo);` - E se a divisão der uma dízima periódica, o que ele deveria fazer? Do jeito que está, vai dar `ArithmeticException`.

Comment: Com 10 funciona porque 10 é divisor de 100. 15 não é divisor de 100, então vai dar essa exceção. Você tem que dizer o que você quer fazer quando a divisão dá uma dízima periódica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema já foi indicado pelo @VitorStafusa nos comentários, que é o fato de a divisão resultar numa dizima infinita periódica, no método `divide`.

Se considerar um prazo de 15 meses, a divisão que está a fazer é `100/15` que dá `6.6666666` infinitamente.

Exemplo do problema em código (com o valor 15 forçado):

```
BigDecimal v1 = new BigDecimal(100);
BigDecimal v2 = new BigDecimal(15);     
BigDecimal v3 = v1.divide(v2);

System.out.println(v3);
```

Que gera uma exceção no método `divide`:

> java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result.

[Veja a exceção a ocorrer no Ideone](https://ideone.com/CcKDUp)

**Solução**

A solução para este problema é na verdade simples. Precisa apenas de alterar a sua chamada ao método `divide` indicando em quantas casas decimais quer o resultado e o modo de arredondamento:

```
BigDecimal v3 = v1.divide(v2, 4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
//casas decimais--------------^ ,  ^-------- modo de arredondamento
```

[Veja também este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/0ZRLq9)

Tem à sua disposição 3 modos de arredondamento:

- `HALF_DOWN`
- `HALF_UP`
- `HALF_EVEN`

Comment: `HALF_EVEN` é o chamado arredondamento bancário. Estatisticamente, é o que gera menos erros em um conjunto grande de operações. Devido a essa natureza de gerar poucos erros, ele é usado pelos bancários pra fazer contas

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Sim faz sentido pois não vai sempre para o mesmo lado, logo com uma larga quantidade de cálculos o erro é menor, estatisticamente falando